# Error Container Widget does not have height when be wrapped under Expanded widget

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm struggling with this error. Please help

Here is my code:

`Expanded( flex: 1, child: Container( margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 5), decoration: BoxDecoration( color: Colors.grey[300], ), ), ),`

My file:
https://gist.github.com/ninoorta/0ddca1ec38984e61a50729eec7eb0eec

Answer (score 0):

To avoid error The expanded widget must be inside a row or column so that It can expand itself according to data inside it.

```
Column(
    children: [
      Expanded( flex: 1, child: Container( margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 5),height: 400, decoration: BoxDecoration( color: Colors.grey[300], ), ), ),
    ],
  );
```

Comment: My  mistake, i wrap it inside a column too but it still is that err.

Comment: you must provide some more details what's inside an expanded widget

Comment: I will edit with my git link for more detail @@